# Using sed to edit lines in a file with a variable

Tags: sed, awk

I need to edit lines in a file using `sed`. Now the problem is I am replacing a particular pattern with a combination of text and number. This number is a variable which keeps on incrementing for every subsequent line. Now as `sed` executes the command for all lines in one go, it is replacing the pattern found with the text and fixed number (i.e initial value of number).

For example:

```
k = 10
sed "s/raj/ram${k++}/"
```

Answer (score 2):

If your file is pretty small, this might work:

```
#!/bin/bash
for n in {1..40}
do
    sed -i $n's/raj/ram'$n'/' file
done
```

It iterates over the file 40 times, and always replaces just 1 line. If you want to increment a counter not by line number, but by the number of lines you changed, you have to do it differently, with 2 variables, but the sed-command would be similar - n wouldn't be set by the loop.

sed -i changes the file in place, so if you want to keep the original, you have to make a copy first.

It can be done in a oneliner, if you prefer that:

```
for n in {1..40}; do sed -i $n's/raj/ram '$n'/' file ; done
```

Choosing the correct size instead of 40 automatically is possible too.

Comment: You can use `$(seq $(wc -l <input.txt))` instead of `{1..40}` for all lines of a specific file.

Comment: Horribly inefficient on large files...

Comment: Yes, but no problem for small ones. Why I introduced it with `if your file is pretty small, ...`.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -v n=10 '{sub(/raj/, "ram" n); print; n++}'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are times to use `sed`, and there are times to not use it.
Because `sed` doesn't have built-in arithmetic, just use something else.
You can hack sed to do it (without a for-loop), but it is rather pointless and just a messy kludge compared to using something more suited.

With this input data:

```
printf '%s\n' 'a.raj' 'yyy' 'zzz' 'b.raj c.raj' >file
num=10 # start with this value
```

---

Here is a perl method, which increments **each and every** occurrence of `raj` (not just once per matched line)

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{ $num='$((num-1))' }
          s/raj/ram.($num+=1)/ge' file
```

output:

```
a.ram10
yyy
zzz
b.ram11 c.ram12
```

---

Here is another *perl* version, which increments `raj` only **once per matched line** (ie. multiple matches on the same line have the same numeric suffix).

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{ $num='$num' }
          if(/raj/){ s/raj/ram.$num/ge; $num+=1 }' file
```

output:

```
a.ram10  
yyy  
zzz  
b.ram11 c.ram11
```

---

see: [When should I NOT use sed](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq6.html#s6.4)