# Use sed to replace line of text with new line including variable

Tags: text-processing, sed

I was looking at this solution: [Using sed to edit lines in a file with a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19728/48151) and tried to apply it to my situation, but I have only recently discovered `sed` and haven't got the hang of it yet.

If I have a file located `/tmp/mary.txt` and it looks like this:

```
Mary had a little lamb
with fleece as white as
snow. Everywhere that
Mary went, the lamb was
sure to go.
```

I want to replace a line of text in this file, specifically:

`Mary had a little lamb` -> `Mary had 2 little lambs`

I used this:

```
sed -i 's/*.had a little lamb.*/Mary had $(nproc) little lambs/' /etc/mary.txt
```

I am using `-i` for **inplace** and `s/` for **substitute** and it throws error:

```
sed: 1: "mary.txt": extra characters at the end of g command
```

---

The other thing I am trying to do, is replace the word "lamb" on the first line with the result of `echo $PATH`

```
sed -i 's/*.had a little lamb.*/ Mary had a little '$(echo $PATH)'/' /etc/mary.txt
```

This throws the same error as above. I know these are two different scenarios, but can it be shown to me what I did wrong, so I can use this in future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use double quotes to have the var evaluated properly:

```
$ var=43
$ sed "s/.*had a little lamb.*/Mary had $var little lambs/" file
Mary had 43 little lambs
with fleece as white as
snow. Everywhere that
Mary went, the lamb was
sure to go.
```

See [Jacob Minshall's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117492/40596) regarding the `.*` instead of `*.`. I had written the `sed` command from scratch, so I did not notice the error in the original code.

Comment: +1 for the answer and +100 for your avatar. És realment molt trist.

Comment: Excellent. I didn't understand the `.*` and `*.` were causing the issue. Thank you. And the double quotes I know understand. I tried it out a couple of times doing different things.

Comment: @terdon ho és :( But we are lucky to have a lifetime to keep listening Paco's art.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because you have `*.` at the beginning, but you want to have `.*`

The . means any character, while the * means zero or more of the preceding character, which there isn't one of

Comment: ah yes, and @fedorqui definitely got it, double quotes as well

Comment: Thank you for explaining what `.*` actually means. I have had trouble understanding that part.